# What's the proper way to use this extension in AngularJS code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using a framework called [Radiant UI](https://github.com/joeriedel/RadiantUI), which is a way to get HTML5 UI into Unreal Engine 4. I'm trying to pick up some modern Javascript while I do that, so I'm building the UI in AngularJS.

My understanding of Angular is still pretty weak though, and I'm a bit confused about what the best practice is here. The extension injects the following Javascript when it sets up.

```
var RadiantUI;
if (!RadiantUI)
  RadiantUI = {};
(function() {
  RadiantUI.TriggerEvent = function() {
    native function TriggerEvent();
    return TriggerEvent(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
  };
  RadiantUI.SetCallback = function(name, callback) {
    native function SetHook();
    return SetHook(name, callback);
  };
  RadiantUI.RemoveCallback = function(name) {
    native function RemoveHook();
    return RemoveHook(name);
  };
})();;
```

So this is simply pushing RadiantUI into the global namespace. That would be fine if the extension was always there, but it isn't. In the test environment (Chrome), it's not there. It's only there when running in the game engine. That, combined with the fact that globals suck, means I want to encapsulate it.

In the previous iteration of this, I had it wrapped in an AMD module, and it worked well. Like this:

```
define([], function()
{
    if ("RadiantUI" in window)
    {
        console.log("RadiantUI in global scope already!");
        return window.RadiantUI;
    }

    var RadiantUI;
    if (!RadiantUI) {
        RadiantUI = {};
        RadiantUI.TriggerEvent = function() {}
        RadiantUI.SetCallback = function() {}
        RadiantUI.RemoveCallback = function() {}
    }

    console.log("Using fake RadiantUI bindings");

    return RadiantUI;
});
```

**So here's what I want to do:**

I want to include radiant as a dependency to my app/stateProvider and have it injected, much the same way it would be in AMD. With the stub methods in place if the extension isn't present. What's the proper approach to this? A module? A service provider?

**UPDATE: This is the working code using the answer given.**

```
var myapp = angular.module('bsgcProtoApp', ['ui.router' ]);

myapp.value('radiant', window.RadiantUI || {
    TriggerEvent: function()
    {
        console.log("TriggerEvent called");

    },
    SetCallback: function(name, callback)
    {
        console.log("Setcallback called");

    },
    RemoveCallback: function(name)
    {
        console.log("RemoveCallback called");
    }
});

myapp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider )
{
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/mainmenu");

    $stateProvider.state('mainmenu',
    {
        name: "mainmenu",
        url: "/mainmenu",
        templateUrl: 'templates/mainmenu.html',
        controller: ['$scope', 'radiant', function($scope, radiant)
        {
            $scope.tester = function()
            {
                radiant.TriggerEvent("DuderDude");
                console.log("Duder!");
            }               
        }],
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You presumably have an Angular module or app. For the sake of this answer, let's call it `MyApp`.

Now you can do

```
MyApp.value("RadiantUI", window.RadiantUI || {
    TriggerEvent = function(){},
    //... more properties
});
```

Now to access this value as a dependency in a controller for example, you'd do this

```
MyApp.controller(["$scope", "RadiantUI", function($scope, RadiantUI){
    // ... controller code ...
}]);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I use "radiant" instead of RadiantUI and I get 'module 'radiant' is not available...'

Also, the syntax of TriggerEvent seems wrong (= instead of :)

Comment: Sounds like you're using `radiant` as a dependency on your app instead of your controller, or something else inside your app. We haven't created a `radiant` module, just a value that resides inside the MyApp module. If you're specifying  your app module as `MyApp = angular.module("MyApp", ["radiant"])`, you should remove radiant from your dependency list there. If you'd like to define radiant as its own module, let me know and I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show the code. Please pick it apart. :)

Comment: where is `myapp` defined?

Comment: Good catch! That was the error. However, fixing it by removing my forgotten 'radiant' reference in the modules changes the error to: '$scope is not defined' - I assume some dumbass syntax error on my part? The error says it's the first $scope, the one immediately after controller:

Comment: Yes, the elements inside the array before your controller function should be strings. They specify the names of your dependencies, which will then be passed in as arguments. You can also just pass a function as a controller, in which case your dependencies will be resolved by argument name, but this causes issues when your code is minimized. Using this array syntax, you allow the argument names of your controllers to be minimized, and still get the dependencies you want. More info on this:https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#dependency-annotation

Comment: `controller: [$scope, 'radiant', function($scope, radiant)` becomes `controller: ['$scope', 'radiant', function($scope, radiant)`.

Comment: If you have any other problems with this, I'm hanging out in the Stack Overflow JS chatroom: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript